# Content Editable Div - Update cursor position after .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Using a contenteditable div, I'd like to highlight words that meet a certain criteria. One of which is if the content the user has entered has reached the allowed maximum length of that area.

I've kind of got something working - but once it reaches the threshold, the cursor position resets back to the beginning (and the user is effectively typing in reverse!).

I need this to work in IE8+.

Is there some way to get the position and set it back where it was before I replaced the contents of the area, or is my line of thinking all wrong?

Thanks

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vfgLjf0c/

```
$(document).on("keypress", "div#editableContent", function(e) {

    var element = $(this);

    // KEYUP
    if (e.type == "keypress") {
        var curLen  = element.text().length;
        var maxLen  = element.attr("data-maxlength");
        if (curLen > maxLen) {

            var overHang    = element.text().substr(maxLen);
                overHang    = "<em style='background: #fcc;'>" + overHang + "</em>";
            var newString   = element.text().substr(0, maxLen) + overHang;
            $(this).html(newString);


        }
    }

});
```

**UPDATE** Answered my own question - see below.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This issue has been resolved here by user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159246/alan0xd7

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31498234/1266457