# ContentEditable div - all HTML after the first 'x' characters

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I've been working on a condenteditable div, whereby I highlight text when it goes over a defined maximum length.

Codepen here:
http://codepen.io/doublesidedstickytape/pen/NqBMXR

It works out OK - unless a user press Return - then it breaks!

I'm thinking that I could could get all the HTML content after the first [x] amount of characters, then loop through each of the  elements (which act as new lines) - to wrap a highlight class around them in my hidden div.

I'm not sure how to achieve this though.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div contenteditable="true" data-maxlength="10" class="editable"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="readonly"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "div.editable", function(event) {

  // GOOD TO STORE THIS IN A VAR
  // PREVENTS THE BROWSER HAVING TO 
  // FIGURE OUT WHAT $(this) IS
  // EACH TIME YOU CALL IT
  var element = $(this);

  // KEYUP  
  if (event.type == "keyup") {

    var maximumLength = element.attr("data-maxlength");
    var currentLength = element.text().length;
    var content = element.text();

    // CURRENT LENGTH IS GREATER THAN
    // THE SPECIFIED MAXIMUM LENGTH
    if (currentLength > maximumLength) {
      var over = element.html().substr(maximumLength);
      over = "<span class='highlight'>" + over + "</span>";
      content = element.html().substr(0, maximumLength) + over;
    }
    $("div.readonly").html(content);

  }

});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #444;
}

div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

div.editable,
div.readonly {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div.editable {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00aeed;
  outline: none;
}

div.readonly {
  z-index: -99;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

span.highlight {
  background: #fcc !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "div.editable", function(event) {

  // GOOD TO STORE THIS IN A VAR
  // PREVENTS THE BROWSER HAVING TO 
  // FIGURE OUT WHAT $(this) IS
  // EACH TIME YOU CALL IT
  var element = $(this);

  // KEYUP  
  if (event.type == "keyup") {

    var maximumLength = element.attr("data-maxlength");
    var currentLength = element.text().length;
    var content = element.text();

    // CURRENT LENGTH IS GREATER THAN
    // THE SPECIFIED MAXIMUM LENGTH
    if (currentLength > maximumLength) {
      var over = element.html().substr(maximumLength);
      over = "<span class='highlight'>" + over + "</span>";
      content = element.html().substr(0, maximumLength) + over;
    }
    $("div.readonly").html(content);

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #444;
}
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
div.editable,
div.readonly {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div.editable {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00aeed;
  outline: none;
}
div.readonly {
  z-index: -99;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}
span.highlight {
  background: #fcc !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div contenteditable="true" data-maxlength="10" class="editable"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="readonly"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't just use `substr` because you will break any child elements that's in the content. When you press enter, the new line is created with a `<div>` element.

Comment: What you can do is, loop through all the child elements in the content, and then highlight their text as necessary. Maybe it will work.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - but I'm not sure how to get all the elements *after* the first 10 characters in the contenteditable div (accounting for any potential HTML in the first ten characters)

Comment: I made some quick edits [here](http://codepen.io/alan0xd7/pen/bdjKra)... it works, to a certain extend. Maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: @alan0xd7 Thank you very much - I'll have a play with it and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out a solution, see: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/6o1sr5fg/

- If there are text that needs highlighting, first we just copy over the content HTML to `div.readonly` for further processing. If no highlighting is required, we just empty the `div`.
- The `collectTextNodes()` function iterates through all the DOM nodes in the content HTML, and collects all text nodes. The collected nodes would only contain text, and no child nodes.
- For all the text nodes we collected, we run them through the `highlight()` function to highlight the text.
- `highlight()` works by first skipping `maximumLength` number of characters, then wrap everything in `<span class='highlight'>`.

Comment: Perfect - and a nice elegant solution too. 
Thank you for taking the time to work on this - I really appreciate it.

I want to share this solution on Github (https://github.com/doublesidedstickytape/content-editable-highlight) - I have uploaded the original (non-working version) and I'd very much like it if you added your fix to it so you can be amply credited.

I'm also thinking it'd be nice to make this a jQuery plugin too (perhaps adding the display div on initialisation) - need to have a think about it.

Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Sounds good, I'll take a look at your Github project when I have time.

Comment: Brill - i've only just created it so it won't be too exciting!